# Is it possible to both override AND hide a property from a base class, and then have one implemented in terms of the other?

Tags: c#

I've found a bug in our code, where we have a class which inherits from `System.Data.Common.DbParameter`, and it *hides* the `Precision` & `Scale` properties by declaring them to return `short` (instead of `byte` like in the base class).

To avoid a breaking change, I'd like to leave the `short` properties there, but then override the `byte` properties to be implemented in terms of the `short` ones (not going to worry too much about what happens when there's an overflow on get/set for now, since in practice the values *should* fit in a `byte`)

But I'm not sure how to actually do that, syntactically. When I try to do

```
        public override byte Precision
        {
            get
            {
                return <ClassName>.Precision;
            }
        }

        public new short Precision
        {
            // stuff
        }
```

It seems like it's still referring to the `byte` version of the property? How do I explicitly refer to the `short` version?

Edit: After fiddling a bit, it's giving an error directly on the second declaration of the property, that it's already been defined, so not sure if they can even be both defined in the same class?

Comment: There is no way to declare two properties with the same name within the same class!, you can still use explicit casting to your short type variable  `(byte)Precision`  convert it to byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a class cannot both override and hide a property. That implies that the class is declaring two properties with the same name, which is illegal. From the [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#153-class-members):

> The name of a constant, field, property, or event shall differ from the names of all other members declared in the same class.

One way to work around this is by adding an intermediate class in the inheritance hierarchy. Suppose your class `YourClass` inherits from `SomeOtherClass`, you can add an `Intermidate` class to put your override implementation in, like this:

```
class Intermediate: SomeOtherClass {
    public override byte Precision {
        get {
            // implement this...
        }
    }     
}

class YourClass: Intermediate {

    public new short Precision => ((Intermediate)this).Precision;
}
```