# Can't override a virtual property in C#?

Tags: c#

I've just written the following class (to try & resolve [Is it possible to both override AND hide a property from a base class, and then have one implemented in terms of the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276682/is-it-possible-to-both-override-and-hide-a-property-from-a-base-class-and-then/76277336#76277336))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Text;

namespace Simba.ADO.Net
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to get around the fact that a single class cannot both override & hide a property.
    /// 
    /// This class overrides DbParameter.Precision &amp; DbParameter.Scale to forward to some abstract Getter/Setter
    /// methods so that SParameter can implement those methods and also hide those properties with versions
    /// that take/return short instead of byte (for backwards compatibility w/ SEN 10.2)
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class SAbstractParameter : DbParameter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the total number of decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        public override byte Precision
        {
            get
            {
                return (byte)GetPrecision();
            }
            set
            {
                SetPrecision(value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the number of fractional decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        public override byte Scale
        {
            get
            {
                return (byte)GetScale();
            }
            set
            {
                SetScale(value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the total number of decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract void SetPrecision(short precision);

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the total number of decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract short GetPrecision();

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the number of fractional decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract void SetScale(short scale);

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the number of fractional decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract short GetScale();
    }
}
```

But when I compile it, I get the errors

```
error CS0115: 'SAbstractParameter.Precision': no suitable method found to override
error CS0115: 'SAbstractParameter.Scale': no suitable method found to override
```

But DbParameter is documented to have those as virtual properties?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbparameter.precision?view=net-7.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbparameter.scale?view=net-7.0

What am I missing?

Edit: Updated the code to explicitly qualify DbParameter & explicitly implement the interface methods, but still getting strange errors

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Text;

namespace Simba.ADO.Net
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to get around the fact that a single class cannot both override & hide a property.
    /// 
    /// This class overrides DbParameter.Precision &amp; DbParameter.Scale to forward to some abstract Getter/Setter
    /// methods so that SParameter can implement those methods and also hide those properties with versions
    /// that take/return short instead of byte (for backwards compatibility w/ SEN 10.2)
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class SAbstractParameter : System.Data.Common.DbParameter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the total number of decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        public override byte System.Data.IDbDataParameter.Precision
        {
            get
            {
                return (byte)GetPrecision();
            }
            set
            {
                SetPrecision(value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or set the number of fractional decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        public override byte System.Data.IDbDataParameter.Scale
        {
            get
            {
                return (byte)GetScale();
            }
            set
            {
                SetScale(value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the total number of decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract void SetPrecision(short precision);

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the total number of decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract short GetPrecision();

        /// <summary>
        /// Set the number of fractional decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract void SetScale(short scale);

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the number of fractional decimal places in the value.
        /// </summary>
        protected abstract short GetScale();
    }
}
```

- 

```
SAbstractParameter.cs(22,59,22,68): error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
SAbstractParameter.cs(22,59,22,68): error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
SAbstractParameter.cs(37,59,37,64): error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
SAbstractParameter.cs(37,59,37,64): error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
SAbstractParameter.cs(22,30,22,58): error CS0540: 'SAbstractParameter.IDbDataParameter.Precision': containing type does not implement interface 'IDbDataParameter'
SAbstractParameter.cs(37,30,37,58): error CS0540: 'SAbstractParameter.IDbDataParameter.Scale': containing type does not implement interface 'IDbDataParameter'
SAbstractParameter.cs(22,59,22,68): error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
SAbstractParameter.cs(22,59,22,68): error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
SAbstractParameter.cs(37,59,37,64): error CS0106: The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
SAbstractParameter.cs(37,59,37,64): error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
SAbstractParameter.cs(22,30,22,58): error CS0540: 'SAbstractParameter.IDbDataParameter.Precision': containing type does not implement interface 'IDbDataParameter'
SAbstractParameter.cs(37,30,37,58): error CS0540: 'SAbstractParameter.IDbDataParameter.Scale': containing type does not implement interface 'IDbDataParameter'
```

Comment: I copied your code and it works for me. Do you have another class called DbParameter in your namespace or in any of the other namespaces you imported (including global usings)?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, [compiles fine in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rMP0zJ).

Comment: If it's some configuration issue in my project or something local to my machine, how do I figure out what it is?

Comment: @Bwmat: By following the usual steps to create a [mcve]: Create a new project A containing just the code from the fiddle. Does the problem still occur? If yes, it's something local to your machine. If no, it's something in your project. In the latter case, gradually copy stuff from your project to project A until the problem re-appears. If you copied everything from your project to project A and the problem still does not re-appear, use a diff tool to find the final remaining differences between your project and project A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I was targeting .NET 3.5 & .NET Standard 2.0, so when I went to look at the documentation (on MSDN, which seems wrong in this respect anyways) & 'go to definition' in the IDE, I was seeing the latter version of the DbParameter class, while those properties changed from being explicit (non-virtual) interface implementations to public virtual in 4.5.1 (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.0-4.5.1), so the error was coming from the .NET 3.5 part of the compilation, where there really were no such properties to override in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 properties you're trying to override are also explicit interface implementations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbparameter?view=net-7.0#explicit-interface-implementations

You would need to explicitly override them:

```
public override byte DbDataParameter.Scale
```

And so forth.

Comment: See my edit, that didn't seem to help.